# how to write and read components using TMemoryStrream

Tags: c++

I have been trying for about 2 weeks to write an object of an arbitrary class derived from `TComponent` on a `TMemoryStream` object using its `writecomponent` method and retrieve this object again using `readcomponent` method. Although I thought this was an easy task, I cannot make it work properly. Actually there is no compilation error but the object's attributes are not loaded correctly. Please help me find what I did wrong. Here is my code snippet.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include <tchar.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

#pragma argsused

using namespace std;

class Woman : public TComponent
{
    private:
    int Age;
    public:
    UnicodeString Name;
    Woman(TComponent* _Owner, int InAge, UnicodeString InName)
        : TComponent(_Owner)
    {
        Age = InAge;
        Name = InName;
    }
    int GetAge()
    {
        return Age;
    }
};

void RegisterClassesWithStreamingSystem(void)
{

  #pragma startup RegisterClassesWithStreamingSystem

  Classes::RegisterClass(__classid(Woman));
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Woman* FirstWoman = new Woman(NULL, 25, "Anjelina");
    UnicodeString as;
    auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> MStr(new TMemoryStream);
    auto_ptr<TStringStream> SStr(new TStringStream(as));

    MStr->WriteComponent(FirstWoman);
    MStr->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    ObjectBinaryToText(MStr.get(), SStr.get());
    SStr->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    as = SStr->DataString;

    auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> pms(new TMemoryStream);
    auto_ptr<TStringStream> pss(new TStringStream(as));
    TComponent *pc;

    ObjectTextToBinary(pss.get(), pms.get());
    pms->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

    pc = pms->ReadComponent(NULL);


    Woman* AWoman;
    AWoman = dynamic_cast<Woman*>(pc);

    cout << AWoman->GetAge() << endl;
    cout << AWoman->Name.c_str() << endl;

    FirstWoman->Free();
    pc->Free();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because

1. your `Woman` class does not have any `__published` read/write properties.  The `WriteComponent()` and `ReadComponent()` methods are part of the DFM streaming system, and DFMs rely on RTTI of published properties to do their work.
2. a DFM cannot construct instances of your class because it does not a compatible constructor, you are using a custom constructor that a DFM cannot call.

You need to update your class accordingly, eg:

```
class Woman : public TComponent
{
private:
    int fAge;
    UnicodeString fName;

public:
    __fastcall Woman(TComponent* Owner)
        : TComponent(Owner)
    {
    }

    __fastcall Woman(TComponent* Owner, int InAge, const UnicodeString &InName)
        : TComponent(Owner)
    {
        fAge = InAge;
        fName = InName;
    }

__published:
    __property int Age = {read=fAge, write=fAge};
    __property UnicodeString Name = {read=fName, write=fName};
};
```

And then you can do this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto_ptr<Woman> FirstWoman(new Woman(NULL, 25, L"Anjelina"));

    auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> MStr(new TMemoryStream);
    auto_ptr<TStringStream> SStr(new TStringStream(L""));

    MStr->WriteComponent(FirstWoman.get());
    MStr->Position = 0;
    ObjectBinaryToText(MStr.get(), SStr.get());
    SStr->Position = 0;
    UnicodeString as = SStr->DataString;

    auto_ptr<TStringStream> pss(new TStringStream(as));
    auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> pms(new TMemoryStream);

    ObjectTextToBinary(pss.get(), pms.get());
    pms->Position = 0;

    auto_ptr<TComponent> pc(pms->ReadComponent(NULL));
    Woman* AWoman = static_cast<Woman*>(pc.get());

    cout << AWoman->Age << endl;
    cout << AWoman->Name.c_str() << endl;

    FirstWoman.reset();
    pc.reset();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Or this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto_ptr<Woman> FirstWoman(new Woman(NULL, 25, L"Anjelina"));

    auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> MStr(new TMemoryStream);
    auto_ptr<TStringStream> SStr(new TStringStream(L""));

    MStr->WriteComponent(FirstWoman.get());
    MStr->Position = 0;
    ObjectBinaryToText(MStr.get(), SStr.get());
    SStr->Position = 0;
    UnicodeString as = SStr->DataString;

    auto_ptr<TStringStream> pss(new TStringStream(as));
    auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> pms(new TMemoryStream);

    ObjectTextToBinary(pss.get(), pms.get());
    pms->Position = 0;

    auto_ptr<Woman> SecondWoman(new Woman(NULL));
    pms->ReadComponent(SecondWoman.get());

    cout << SecondWoman->Age << endl;
    cout << SecondWoman->Name.c_str() << endl;

    FirstWoman.reset();
    SecondWoman.reset();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear Remy. I love you man. It worked. you are a genius