# how to retrieve inner objects of an object properly using TMemoryStream and TStringStream

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe

I have 2 classes named Woman and Man. They have been registered for streaming system. Woman class has some attributes and most importantly an instance of class Man in it. Using TMemoryStream and TStringStream classes I was able to retrieve all attributes of Woman but Man*, by WriteComponent and ReadComponent methods of TmemoryStream class. Actually the compiler throws an exception and the reason is that Man* is NULL and is not loaded properly. In my program I need to load all attributes including simple data types and instances of other written classes. Please give me advice how to load Woman object properly so that Man* is not NULL any more. here is my code snippet.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include <tchar.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

#pragma argsused

using namespace std;

class Man : public TComponent
{
    private:
    double fMoney;
    public:
    __fastcall Man(TComponent* _Owner,double InMoney)
        : TComponent(_Owner)
        {
            fMoney = InMoney;
        }
    __published:
    __property double Money = {read=fMoney, write=fMoney};
};

class Woman : public TComponent
{
    private:
    int fAge;
    UnicodeString fMyName;
    Man* fManInClass;
    public:
    __fastcall Woman(TComponent* _Owner, int InAge, UnicodeString InName)
        : TComponent(_Owner)
    {
        fAge = InAge;
        fMyName = InName;
        fManInClass = new Man(this, 0);
    }
    __published:
    __property int Age = {read=fAge, write=fAge};
    __property UnicodeString MyName = {read=fMyName, write=fMyName};
    __property Man* ManInClass = {read = fManInClass, write = fManInClass};
};


void RegisterClassesWithStreamingSystem(void)
{

  #pragma startup RegisterClassesWithStreamingSystem
  Classes::RegisterClass(__classid(Man));
  Classes::RegisterClass(__classid(Woman));
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Woman* FirstWoman = new Woman(NULL, 25, "Anjelina");
    FirstWoman->ManInClass->Money = 2000;
    UnicodeString as;
    auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> MStr(new TMemoryStream);
    auto_ptr<TStringStream> SStr(new TStringStream(as));

    MStr->WriteComponent(FirstWoman);
    MStr->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    ObjectBinaryToText(MStr.get(), SStr.get());
    SStr->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    as = SStr->DataString;

    auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> pms(new TMemoryStream);
    auto_ptr<TStringStream> pss(new TStringStream(as));
    TComponent *pc;

    ObjectTextToBinary(pss.get(), pms.get());
    pms->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

    pc = pms->ReadComponent(NULL);


    Woman* AWoman = dynamic_cast<Woman*>(pc);

    cout << AWoman->Age << endl;
    cout << AWoman->MyName.c_str() << endl;
    cout << AWoman->ManInClass->Money << endl; // AWoman->ManInClass is NULL -> Exception

    delete FirstWoman;
    pc->Free();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `TMemoryStream` and `TStringStream`? These aren't standard c++ classes. Are you using a specific framework actually?

Comment: yes. I am using C++ builder and coding in Embarcadero XE1

Comment: At least we have a tag for [tag:c++builder], added that. Otherwise your question is way too broad. We don't know about that specific framework (well, at least not the bigger part of the c++ community).

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a similar problem I described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37733305/65863) to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733162/) - namely, that your `Woman` class is defining a constructor that has *custom* parameters, and as such the DFM streaming system *cannot* call that constructor when reading a `Woman` from a DFM stream.  That is why your `Man*` pointer is NULL - your constructor is not being called to initialize that pointer.

There is only *one* constructor signature that the DFM can call:

```
__fastcall <classname>(TComponent* Owner)
```

You cannot change that signature.  You *can* define additional overloaded constructors with extra parameters as needed, but the above constructor is required for DFM streaming.

Try this instead:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include <tchar.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

#pragma argsused

using namespace std;

class Man : public TComponent
{
private:
    double fMoney;

public:
    __fastcall Man(TComponent* Owner)
        : TComponent(Owner)
    {
    }

    __fastcall Man(TComponent* Owner, double InMoney)
        : TComponent(Owner)
    {
        fMoney = InMoney;
    }

__published:
    __property double Money = {read=fMoney, write=fMoney};
};

class Woman : public TComponent
{
private:
    int fAge;
    UnicodeString fMyName;
    Man* fManInClass;

    void __fastcall SetManInClass(Man *Value)
    {
        fManInClass->Money = Value->Money;
    }

public:
    __fastcall Woman(TComponent* Owner)
        : TComponent(Owner)
    {
        fManInClass = new Man(this);
        fManInClass->SetSubComponent(true);
    }

    __fastcall Woman(TComponent* Owner, int InAge, UnicodeString InName)
        : TComponent(Owner)
    {
        fAge = InAge;
        fMyName = InName;
        fManInClass = new Man(this);
        fManInClass->SetSubComponent(true);
    }

__published:
    __property int Age = {read=fAge, write=fAge};
    __property UnicodeString MyName = {read=fMyName, write=fMyName};
    __property Man* ManInClass = {read = fManInClass, write = SetManInClass};
};

void RegisterClassesWithStreamingSystem(void)
{
  Classes::RegisterClass(__classid(Man));
  Classes::RegisterClass(__classid(Woman));
}
#pragma startup RegisterClassesWithStreamingSystem

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto_ptr<Woman> FirstWoman(new Woman(NULL, 25, L"Anjelina"));
    FirstWoman->ManInClass->Money = 2000;

    auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> MStr(new TMemoryStream);
    auto_ptr<TStringStream> SStr(new TStringStream(L""));

    MStr->WriteComponent(FirstWoman);
    MStr->Position = 0;
    ObjectBinaryToText(MStr.get(), SStr.get());
    SStr->Position = 0;
    UnicodeString as = SStr->DataString;

    auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> pms(new TMemoryStream);
    auto_ptr<TStringStream> pss(new TStringStream(as));

    ObjectTextToBinary(pss.get(), pms.get());
    pms->Position = 0;

    auto_ptr<TComponent> pc(pms->ReadComponent(NULL));

    Woman* AWoman = static_cast<Woman*>(pc.get());    

    cout << AWoman->Age << endl;
    cout << AWoman->MyName.c_str() << endl;
    cout << AWoman->ManInClass->Money << endl;

    pc.reset();
    FirstWoman.reset();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Also notice the extra calls to `fManInClass->SetSubComponent()`.  That is needed if you ever want to use your `Woman` component in the Form Designer at design-time and set its properties and sub-properties in the Object Inspector.  The DFM streaming system also makes use of the internal `csSubComponent` flag that `SetSubComponent()` sets/clears.  This is a signal to the VCL system that the `fManInClass` object is owned by the `Woman` object and has special handling.

Also notice the setter method added for the `ManInClass` property.  Since `Woman` owns the `Man` object, you don't want to allow an outside caller to change the value of the `fManInClass` variable, thus causing a memory leak and ownership conflicts.  A published property needs to be read/write in order to be DFM-streamable (unless you override the virtual `TComponent::DefineProperties()` method to provide custom streaming), so it needs both a getter and a setter, but you can use class methods to protect access to that variable.

I strongly suggest you get yourself a good book on how to write VCL components.

Comment: thank you again Remy. you are awesome. would you please give me a name for a good C++ builder book which covers such stuff like writing vcl components and the subjects you think I may find useful in this level?